# the if statement not running inside the async function

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement, asynchronous, redux

```
 const readersInfo = useSelector(
  (state:IRootState) => state.reader.readerinfo
);


useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getThisReaderInfoThunk())
}, [dispatch]);


const readerInfo = readersInfo[0]


const onSubmit = async () => {

  console.log("aaabbbccc")
  const recording_data=  await onStartRecord()
console.log(recording_data) //is ok 
   if (readerInfo){

 //this part can't run
    console.log("this is path",recording_data,readerInfo.id,bookId, page)
     dispatch(postAudioRecordThunk(recording_data as string,readerInfo.id,bookId, page))
   }
}
```

when I called the onSubmit function, the aaabbbccc did logged, but the if statement is not running, anyone could help? thx!
the readerInfo is a constant loaded by useSelector from redux which is true in this case

Comment: that would suggest `readersInfo[0]` is falsey ... `console.log(!!readerInfo)` - is it true or false?

Comment: Or that `onStartRecord` never resolves

Comment: console.log(!!readerInfo) = false

Comment: @Dominik `console.log(recording_data) //is ok` so, it resolves

Comment: So we got the issue. `recording_data` is falsy... ;)

Comment: @wing1224 - thats why the code in the `if` doesn't run ... because `readerInfo` is falsy - mystery solved (now you just need to find out why)

Comment: I guess it did resolve for onStartRecord (), because the recording_data could logged out

Comment: @Dominik - no `readerInfo` is falsy

Comment: It's late... Second time I'm wrong in the same comments section... I see myself out :)

Comment: what is `console.log(typeof readersInfo[0])`

Comment: thx @Bravo, but the readerInfo can logged out sth, not sure why it is false....

Comment: console.log(typeof readersInfo[0])=undefined

Comment: well, that's what `readerInfo` is too ... undefined ... falsy ... so why do you think `console.log(readerInfo)` logs something (other than undefined - your code logs `recording_data` it never logs `readerInfo`)

Comment: thx Bravo!, i figure out why it is false finally!